# Segmentation fault on Eigen::SparseMatrix resize

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have a large set of codes ([public on github](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/tree/main/2D_solver)), but it's way too much to put in a question, and I have no idea how to get a mwe (you'll see why), so I'd be happy with just some more suggestions on what could be going wrong.

We have a class, `SC_class`, in [this file](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/blob/main/2D_solver/SC_classes.hpp), with several derived classes. In the derived class `Cylindrical : public SC_class`, we define a few more member variables (sparse matrices from Eigen). In the constructor, we call a function ([line 298 here](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/blob/e2b079ce935f72c230db22eeec1971e2e9d5eb17/2D_solver/SC_classes_derived.cpp#L298)) that resizes these matrices before we use them. The seg fault occurs on [line 317](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/blob/e2b079ce935f72c230db22eeec1971e2e9d5eb17/2D_solver/SC_classes_derived.cpp#L317), but that is exactly how I had [resized the other matrices](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/blob/e2b079ce935f72c230db22eeec1971e2e9d5eb17/2D_solver/SC_classes_derived.cpp#L300)! (Lines 316-318 are 3 ways that I tried to do the same thing but I get the same error.) **If I [define them all the same way](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/blob/e2b079ce935f72c230db22eeec1971e2e9d5eb17/2D_solver/SC_classes.hpp#L145), and resize the [last one](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/blob/e2b079ce935f72c230db22eeec1971e2e9d5eb17/2D_solver/SC_classes_derived.cpp#L317) the same way as the [first one](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/blob/e2b079ce935f72c230db22eeec1971e2e9d5eb17/2D_solver/SC_classes_derived.cpp#L300), why do I only get the seg fault on the last one?** (I say last just since that's the order that I have them right now, but changing the order doesn't change the statement that it crashes on.) The only other thing I've noticed that might help is that sometimes, when I had lines 316-318 commented out, I would get a seg fault right at the end of the program, something after [this line](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/blob/e2b079ce935f72c230db22eeec1971e2e9d5eb17/2D_solver/gl_fdm.cpp#L125).

[Here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=254) it was stated that sometimes the matrix might be too big for the stack or the heap, but when I tried `.resize(1,1)` ([here](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/blob/e2b079ce935f72c230db22eeec1971e2e9d5eb17/2D_solver/SC_classes_derived.cpp#L318)), it still didn't work.

Comment: At first guess, it is an alignment problem. Try using the latest Eigen version. Also use at least C++17 with at least gcc-7/clang-5 as described [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html) which should take care of all alignment issues (since [Eigen 3.3](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1409)). Also, in case you are on Windows, do not use minGW-gcc; it still has problems aligning stuff correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, strangest source of the error; I don't know if anyone else will have something like this, but just in case, I'll share.

I have a [pointer in the main file](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/blob/6846185fde34840becad48b8194aea6dc96e045e/2D_solver/gl_fdm.cpp#L27), but I eventually turn it into an array. At the end of the program, I delete that pointer as if it was an array (since that's what I turned it into), but that was causing one of the seg faults. (Note: I had the line `delete[] eta_BC` [here](https://github.com/zeeekiayh/GL_solver/blob/6846185fde34840becad48b8194aea6dc96e045e/2D_solver/gl_fdm.cpp#L131), but it will also throw an error if you say `delete eta_BC`; **the problem was simply an improper use of pointers.**) To solve it, I simply needed to change the array to an `std::vector`.